# Selenium/Katalon alternative to :visible selector

Tags: selenium-webdriver, katalon-studio

I've learned the other day that Selenium throws exception about the selector if it is CSS selector and contains `:visible`. This is a drawback for me. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Katalon Studio**, you can execute JavaScript (jQuery, in this case).

For example, the following will paint yellow all the `<a>` elements that contain `:visible`:

```
WebUI.executeJavaScript('return $("a:visible").css("backgroundColor", "yellow")', [])
```